# How do i replace vowel(s) from a character with * and get an array of all the possiblities in js

Tags: javascript

Suppose that i have a word "FadTheChad" (or any word that has vowels) and want the vowels replaced with "*" and return all the possibilities (subsets? not sure how i could describe it) of the word in an array.

I tried using String.replace() on the whole string which gave me `F*dTh*Ch*d`. Then i tried looping over the string and doing .replace() again which returned `F*dTheChad, FadTh*Chad, FadTheCh*d`.

is there anyway that i could get something like

```js
[
  'F*dTh*Ch*d',
  'F*dTheChad',
  'F*dTh*Chad',
  'F*dTheCh*d',
  'FadTh*Chad',
  'FadTh*Ch*d',
  'FadTheCh*d'
]
```

Comment: Run the replacer in a loop so that the previous result is the current string, and don't use the g flag in the regex.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @ScottSauyet i had tried using String.replace() which gave me the first result in the codeblock. Then i looped over the characters of the string and replaced them with '\*' which gave me F\*dTheChad, FadTh\*Chad and FadTheCh\*d in order

Comment: Please update the question with a description of your attempt and a note about what went wrong.  See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: yo.. so what is this for :D

Comment: @TheBombSquad basically to catch blacklisted/censored words, so if 'test' is blacklisted and someone does 't*st' in order to evade, they won't be successful :)

Comment: woah.. that's an interesting way of blocking censor bypasses >:D

Comment: however when using the function you might want to break up messages into small chunks(like 12 sized chunks max[`4096 possibilities`]) since trying every asterix combination gets exponentially laggier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function getPossibilities(word) {
    let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']; // 'y'?
    let positions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(word[i]) !== -1) positions.push(i);
    }
    let result = [], count = 2 ** positions.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let newWord = [...word];
        for (let j = 0; j < positions.length; j++) {
            if ((i >> j) & 1) newWord[positions[j]] = '*';
        }
        result.push(newWord.join(''));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I make the word into an array because in JS strings are immutable so I wouldn't be able to modify indices like this.

Comment: your answer works

Comment: seems to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yea u got it in 3 minutes before me gg

Comment: @TheBombSquad gg

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

Ok, now that I understand the question before answering it (see original below for explanation), this can also be answered with a simple recursion:

```js
const addAsterisks = ([c,...cs]) =>
  c == undefined
    ? ['']
    : addAsterisks (cs) .flatMap (
        (w) => 'aeiou' .includes (c) ? [c + w, '*' + w] : [c + w]
      )

console .log (addAsterisks ('FadTheChad'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If the string is empty, we return an array containing the empty string.  Otherwise we recur on the remainder of the string, and for each result, we return an array with the our current character prepended to the result and, if the current character is a vowel, an asterisk prepended to the result.

### Original Answer

(*This answered a different question altogether, based on my misreading.  It's still interesting in its own right.*)

<del>A simple recursion makes this easy:</del>

```js
const addVowels = (str) => 
  str .indexOf ('*') < 0 
    ? str 
    : ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] .flatMap (v => addVowels (str .replace ('*', v)))

console .log (addVowels ('F*dTh*Ch*d'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

<del>If our string contains no asterisks, we are done and simply return it.</del>

<del>If it has an asterisk, `flatMap`ping the results of replacing that with each of the vowels and recurring on the resulting string.</del>

---

For next time, please include some sample code for what you've tried.

Comment: fair point u have below however, your huge array doesn't format the data how the OP wanted ;-;

Comment: You're right.  I misread this as a different question I have seen.  I'll have to look at other answers to see if the implementations can make clear to me the logic of the expected answer.

Comment: @TheBombSqad: Thank you for pointing that out.  I really need to read more carefully before posting.  This is updated now.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is to **find** the vowels, *then* to find all possible combinations by replacing them with star.. pretty nice so here's my attempt

```js
function vowelOptions(text,replacer){
  let isVowel={a:1,e:1,i:1,o:1,u:1}
  let vowels=[], toReturn=[]
  let data=text.split('')
  data.forEach((letter,i)=>{
    if(isVowel[letter]){vowels.push(i)} //location of vowel stored
  })
  for(let i=1;i<Math.pow(2,vowels.length);i++){
    //Math.pow(2,vowels.length) are the number of vowel possibilities
    //i=1 and NOT 0 because default text is now allowed in return
    let dataOption=[...data] //a clone with a possible combination
    let combination=i.toString(2).split('').reverse() //the ones that will be '1' tell me where to put the replacer
    combination.forEach((bool,j)=>{
      if(bool=='1'){dataOption[vowels[j]]=replacer} //vowels to replace in this combination replaced thanks to vowel locations saved above
    })
    toReturn.push(dataOption.join(''))
  }
  return toReturn
}

//now watch it work >:}
console.log(vowelOptions("FadTheChad","*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am way too late, but maybe this is still of interest so someone?

```js
const str="didadumdidum",v=[],
      parts=str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi,
    m=>(v.push(m),"*")).split("*"),
      n=1<<v.length;
  
for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
  let s=i.toString(2)
     .padStart(v.length,"0")
  console.log(
 parts.map((p,j)=>(j--?+s[j]?v[j]:"*":"")+p).join("")
)
}
```

In my approach I used `String.prototype.replace()` with a callback function to collect the vowels in an array while splitting the string into an array (`parts`). The rest is similar to @thebombsquad's approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace Vowel world in string using "e"
 //let vowels = /[aeiou]/gi;
 //let result = str.match(vowels);
 //return result;
 let newstr = str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi,'e')
 return newstr.toUpperCase();
}
//toScottishScreaming();

console.log(toScottishScreaming("ewefpofdfdfkfg  hythythg fgrefek!"));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).